# Can I have some shortcut for language and area change in Google search?

Tags: google-search, localization

When I try to search in another language, I click **Advanced Search → Languages → specific language**. It is a little tiresome if I repeat this for different langauges, and different key words. I wonder if I can make it simplified; for example, move the language choice to the search main page without clicking **Advanced Search**, or even make a button for each of those often-used languages on the main page?

Similar question for geographical region search.

**Added:**
Does `keyword site:*.ru` will make Google search inside Russian websites? What difference is it from searching in either Russian language or Russia country?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the url parameter `hl` in this way:

- `hl=en` (for English)
- `hl=ru` (for Russian)
- `hl=de` (for German)

and so on.

Another possibility is to use [yubnub](http://yubnub.org) search engine.
You can define a new [custom command](http://yubnub.org/command/new?name=) to get search result in desired language.

Suppose that you want to get Google Search result in Russian, you can define a command called `goru` with url defined as `https://www.google.com/#hl=ru&output=search&q=%s`. You can define other command like `goit` (Italian), `gode` (German) and so on by substituting the `hl=` part with correspondent language abbreviation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! 
How about Chinese simplified and Chinese traditional?

Comment: I could be wrong, not an expert on Chinese language, but it should be #hl=zh-CN for simplified Chinese and #hl=zh-TW for traditional Chinese

Comment: Thanks! Does `keyword site:*.ru` will make Google search inside Russian websites? What difference is it from searching in either Russian language or Russia country?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome) you can easily add another search engine and then using the keywords much faster. If you're not using Chrome then you should :)

- Go to `Settings`
- `Manage search engines...`
- at the end of the list you'll have 3 fields
- first: `Google RU`
- second: `glru`
- thrid: `http://google.com/search?q=%s&hl=ru`
- hit `Return`

Now if you type in the [omnibox](http://chrome.blogspot.com/2009/06/get-to-know-omnibox.html) `glru` and press `Tab`, whatever you're going to type there, you'll be searching in Russian Google.

This is just an example so feel free to customize as you wish.