# Is there a +lang:en option in Google Search, like +site:<domain>?

Tags: google-search, localization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I have some shortcut for language and area change in Google search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24831/can-i-have-some-shortcut-for-language-and-area-change-in-google-search)

Is there an option like +lang:en in Google Search, like +site:?

It would restrict results based on language.

Or is there an easy way to switch the language of pages you search in Google, without going into the settings every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to do this, you can format the query string so that it contains the `lr=lang_<language code>` parameter. There is no easier way to do this.